# Want to Install Zpanel with Zentastico on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zpanel

I am very new to Ubuntu and zpanel. What im trying to do is to install zpanel on Ubuntu 14.04 and deploy a wordpress website on it. Based on my research i have come to know that it would require me to install Zentastico in order to add scripts like wordpress or file manager.

I have installed Zpanel on ubuntu but cant see Zentastico anywhere. How can i do that, can anybody help?

I am using terminal from my mac to do all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Zentastico seperately as per the [Zentastico website](http://zantastico.sourceforge.net/).

> Installation 
>   The installation of Zantastico is very simple, Once you have downloaded it and extracted the contents of the ZIP file you will find an INSTALL.TXT file with instructions on how to install.

And as per the readme file inside the Zentastico download:

> > Installing Zantastico
>
> - Please make sure that you follow these instructions closely, If you don't Zantastico may not work properly!
>
>   • Extract the 'zantastico' directory to the 'modules' directory found in the Zpanel folder, Your file structure should look like
>     this:-
>
>   zpanel/modules/zantastico
>
>   Please make sure that you keep the 'zantastico' directory using the same name, otherwise Zantastico will not function correctly!
>
>   • Execute the SQL against your ZPanel Database...
>
>   If your database is MySQL 3.x you will need to execute:- zantastico_sql3.sql
>
>   If your database is MySQL 4.x / 5.x you will need to execute:- zantastico_sql4.sql
>
>   • Enable the Zantastico module in the ZPanel Administration Panel.
>
>   • ALL DONE!!! - Setup should now be complete, Simply test it! - If you have any problems, speak to us at: http://planet.zantastico.org